# How do I subtract two times on Postgres if they are stored as character varying?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has stored columns time_attended and time_departed from a site.

for example time_attended = "16:00" and time_departed = "17:00"

They are stored as character varying fields - how would I find the time difference?

Doing a conversion eg -
SELECT
time_attended::date - time_departed::date
FROM table

throws up the syntax error 'invalid input syntax for type date: "16:00"'

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Those column should be defined as `time` to begin with, not as `varchar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are time values, cast them to a `time` not a `date`

```
select time_attended::time - time_departed::time
from the_table
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks so much! - very simple. How would I convert this to minutes? It returns a data type interval for the difference in hours

Comment: I have managed to convert to mins - thank you for you help